# VBA Insert .csv from website, .csv not in url

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am trying to figure out if there is a way with VBA to download the .csv file at the bottom left of the screen named "Download" at this link:

http://www.redfin.com/homes-for-sale#!excl_ss=true&market=socal&max_price=300000&min_price=50000&num_baths=1.0&num_beds=1&region_id=11203&region_type=6&time_on_market_range=30-&uipt=2&v=8

The .csv doesn't appear to be attached to a URL, which I know how to import, but I can't figure this out.  Any help would be appreciated.

Matt

Answer (score 2):

Try this URL:

http://www.redfin.com/stingray/do/gis-search?market=socal&region_id=11203&region_type=6&excl_ss=true&hoa=&max_listing_approx_size=&max_num_beds=&max_parcel_size=&max_price=300000&max_year_built=&min_listing_approx_size=&min_parcel_size=&min_price=50000&min_year_built=&num_baths=1.0&num_beds=1&open_house=&pkg=-&rd=&sf=1%2C2%2C3&sold_within_days=&status=1&time_on_market_range=30-&uipt=2&v=8&num_homes=500&sp=t&al=1&render=csv

There is actually a URL, it's just hidden and is accessed via some JavaScript Code.

In general, if you're wondering which URL is being used, try the following:

- In Chrome:

  - Press Ctrl-Shift-J; this should bring up the debug console.
  - Click on a button on the bottom left to undock the debug console for convenience; it should now be in a separate window.
  - Go to 'Network' tab.
  - On the website, click the link to download CSV file.
  - Watch for new items appearing in the "Network" tab.  One of them is likely the request to download the CSV file.  Try right-clicking on it, and selecting "Open in a new tab".  If you end up with the CSV file download dialog, then that's the URL you were looking for.
- In Firefox:

  - Install FireBug plug-in, and do something similar to Chrome.

Comment: I used this URL in excel, but it said the filepath is too long (greater than 256)  Does anyone know of anyone workarounds?  My code works with .csv files from short URL's

Comment: @user2113095 please note that ikh answered your original question. Now you have a new problem/question. You will have best luck getting an answer if you post a new question. Also, please indicate what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it does:

> http://www.redfin.com/stingray/do/gis-search?market=socal&region_id=11203&region_type=6&excl_ss=true&hoa=&max_listing_approx_size=&max_num_beds=&max_parcel_size=&max_price=300000&max_year_built=&min_listing_approx_size=&min_parcel_size=&min_price=50000&min_year_built=&num_baths=1.0&num_beds=1&open_house=&pkg=-&rd=&sf=1%2C2%2C3&sold_within_days=&status=1&time_on_market_range=30-&uipt=2&v=8&num_homes=500&sp=t&al=1&render=csv

You can find the URL by using the `Developer Tools` of `IE`, like so:

- Open the website and press `F12`
- In the window that appears (Developer Tools), select the `Pointer Icon`
- After selecting the `Pointer Icon`, click the `Download Link` on the website
- In the `Developer Tools` window you will notice a lot of HTML appears with a line selected; this line contains the link to the CSV.
- Select the text in the `downloadCsv` function within that line: `list.downloadCsv('...text to select...')`
- Add the copied text after `http://www.redfin.com` in the URL.